# Add formats to dataframe and insert in excel using python?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter, openxlsx

i have to insert a database into excel with borders and all values in data frame should be centered i tried doing formatting to cells but does not work

```
df1.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=True,startrow=12,sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.close()
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(s, engine="xlsxwriter")
    writer.book = load_workbook(s)
    workbooks= writer.book
    worksheet = workbooks['Sheet1']
    f1= workbooks.add_format()
    worksheet.conditional_format(12,0,len(df1)+1,7,{'format':f1})
```

can u please help me with this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to lie: I've done this for the first time right now, so this might not be a very good solution. I'm using `openpyxl` because it seems more flexible to me than `XlsxWriter`. I hope you can use it too.

My assumption is that the variable `file_name` contains a valid file name.

First your Pandas step:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=True, startrow=12, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Then the necessary imports from `openpyxl`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle, Alignment, Border, Side
```

Loading the workbook and selecting the worksheet:

```
wb = load_workbook(file_name)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
```

Defining the required style:

```
centered_with_frame = NamedStyle('centered_with_frame')
centered_with_frame.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')
bd = Side(style='thin')
centered_with_frame.border = Border(left=bd, top=bd, right=bd, bottom=bd)
```

Selecting the relevant cells:

```
cells = ws[ws.cell(row=12+1, column=1).coordinate:
           ws.cell(row=12+1+df1.shape[0], column=df1.shape[1]).coordinate]
```

Applying the defined style to the selected cells:

```
for row in cells:
    for cell in row:
        cell.style = centered_with_frame
```

Finally saving the workbook:

```
wb.save(file_name)
```

As I said: This might not be optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i did this by applying format to the data frame directly , since there was some error with add_format() [ATTRIBUTE ERROR]